# How to change the position of a node in a tree view

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm trying to insert my nodes in a specific order. The position of a node comes from the database, it's not any specific sorting. Here's a very simple example of what i have let's say there's a `name` and `positionInList` property.

```
List<stuff> listOfStuff = new List<stuff>();

foreach(stuff in listOfStuff)
{
  myTreeView.Nodes.add(stuff.name);
}
```

I tried changing the index but it's a read only property so i can't do something like `myTreeView.Nodes.add(stuff.name).index = ...`

and `myTreeview.Nodes[stuff.positionInList].add` doesn't work cause the position may refer to a node that wasn't created it. And i'm not really sure this is the syntax to add a node after another one.

I've tried searching for this but i didn't find anyone doing this.

Can anyone provide me with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Insert-method

```
this.treeView1.Nodes.Insert(0, new TreeNode());
```

So if you want to change the position you should remove the node selected node an insert it at the new position.

Comment: I can't make it work the way i want. Let's say i have 3 nodes and my next node that comes from the db has to be in the position 10. With insert i can't make it work.

Comment: so you want to skip the nodes 4,5,6,7,8 and 9 and insert the next node at the position 10. I hope I understood you correctly?